# Disaplay Image on screen(Asp.net Mvc) from sql server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

From database data is in byte[] array ie. image and I want to show it on screen in image tag 
so decided to write Html helper for image, then How to convert that byte data so that I can assign it to src of img tag

Comment: you can use the [Data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to put the base 64 representation of the image directly in the page.

However, this approach can make page quite huge with large images, and can lead to performances and caching problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can also build an aspx page that receive de id of the image in BD as an parameter, this page access you DB, pick the byte[] and just do a response.

Ex.:

In your aspx use like this:

```
    <img src='<%# "ImageCreator.aspx?id=" + varImageID %>'>
```

In ImageCreator's Page_Load do this:

```
    imgID = Request["id"];

    byte[] buffer = ???;//*call something to get this from your DB

    Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
    Response.BinaryWrite(buffer );
```

Hope this can help you.